# c# .net Json get Node

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to get the `title` from `works` in the following Json text:

[Json_Text.html](http://www.admobreklame.com/logo.html)

But I get error when using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var Title = obj["works"][i]["title"] as JArray;

    myTextbox.Text += "\n" + Title.ToString();
}
```

The error is at `myTextbox`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am I doing wrong?

I do get out all the information in "works" => "authors" if I use this:

```
var Title = obj["works"][i]["authors"] as JArray;
```

but that's not what I want.

Comment: Well, what's null? Have you used your debugger? If not, do so and find out. There's nowhere near enough context here for us to have any idea what is going wrong here.

Comment: `myTextbox` is null, so you can't access the properties inside. Where is this code being called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on type of the expression `obj["works"][i]["title"]`

I think it should be a string

```
var Title = obj["works"][i]["title"];
myTextbox.Text += "\n" + Title.ToString();
```

Comment: So unless my edit was bad, what about the exception the OP is getting? Shouldn't the problem be that `myTextbox` is null?

Comment: The problem is `Title.ToString()`. Title is null because of the incorrect cast

Comment: That's quite an assumption, we still have no idea what is actually throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what JSON library you are using, but it looks like you are casting title to an array when it is simply a string.  Authors seems to be an array on the page you linked.

Try something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var Title = obj["works"][i]["title"]; //without the cast

    myTextbox.Text += "\n" + Title.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do:

```
var Title = obj["works"][i]["title"] as JArray;
```

where 'title' is not a JSON array.

Whereas:

```
var Title = obj["works"][i]["authors"] as JArray;
```

works, because if you look at your diagram, you can see that authors is an array, which you then put in to Title.

Title is then null, so you get your exception.